# Alamofire 'Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)' struct

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to make a Alamofire Post request and my Codable struct is failing.

```
var items: [[InspectionUploadItem]?]?

let params : Parameters = ["key" : key, "items": items]

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { response in
```

I simplified the Parameters but my items struct is what is failing.

```
struct InspectionUploadItem: Codable {

  var id: Int = 0
  var type: String = ""
  var value: String?
  var name: String = ""
  var children: [[InspectionUploadItem]]?

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
   case id = "id"
   case type = "type"
   case value = "value"
   case children = "children"
   }
 }
```

The model is correct as I have successfully completed this in Android. I am avoiding manually converting this into a JSON object as this object can extends three sub levels deep and contains dozens of items.

This is my specific error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__SwiftValue)'`

I have found posts with a similar titles point out more obvious mistakes on non-struct models. Is there a way for me to narrow down specifically the location of the error? Is there something more obviously wrong with my code?

Edit: Out going parameters field

```
["key": "keyString", "items": Optional([Optional([CompanyName.InspectionUploadItem(id: 317, type: "TEXT", value: Optional("testing field"), name: "One String", children: nil)])])]
```

Comment: post your received body

Comment: It is a post method, unless you meant my out-going parameters. I just added them above. Is there an issue with my nil "children", or that the array is written as "optional"

Comment: "optional" is the problem. Try removing it !

Comment: @Zyfe3r that is exactly it. Though my "value" field needs to be an optional value, so I will just manually build my items for uploading rather than trying to deal with passing this completed object. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally your issue is that you're passing a Swift struct to a method which uses `JSONSerialization` and the two are incompatible. The correct `request` call to use `Encodable` parameters is `request(_:method:parameters:encoder:headers:)` instead. You'll likely need to redo your root parameters type for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the new `JSONParameterEncoder.prettyPrinted` rather than `JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted`. `JSONParameterEncoder` uses `JSONEncoder` where as `JSONEncoding` uses `JSONSerialization`. `JSONSerialization` doesn't know how to convert `Encodable`s to JSON so it's getting to the struct and throwing and an exception. Example from [the docs](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#post-request-with-json-encoded-parameters):

```
struct Login: Encodable {
    let email: String
    let password: String
}

let login = Login(email: "test@test.test", password: "testPassword")

AF.request("https://httpbin.org/post",
           method: .post,
           parameters: login,
           encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default).response { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

Despite the comments this has nothing to do with optionality (though I would say `[[InspectionUploadItem]?]?` is likely not necessary and hard to work with). All you need to do is define a struct to represent your parameters.

```
struct InspectionUploadParameters: Codable {
    let key: String
    let items: [[InspectionUploadItem]?]?
}
```

then

```
let params = InspectionUploadParameters(key: "keyString", items: items)
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONParameterEncoder.prettyPrinted, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON
```